# Issue with Association in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have a model called Path and at that model, there is a column which I have split it to four numbers and I want to associate these numbers to two models Termlist_path and Termlist but I get the error "undefined method `termlist_list' for "729":String". The code overall replaces some numbers in some tables like path.path with some words stored in termlist table but there is in between table called termlit_path. But my main problem is that path.path is like /729/760/775/783, so I have to split it first to 729, 760, 775, 783 so I can refer every number to a specific word in termlist

The Models:

```
class MuseumObject < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :storage_location
belongs_to :path, :foreign_key => "main_path_id"
belongs_to :production_technique
belongs_to :preservation_material
end
class StorageLocation < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :museum_objects, through: :storage
    belongs_to :storage 
end
class Storage < ApplicationRecord
    has_one  :storage_location 
end
class Path < ApplicationRecord
has_one :termlist_path
has_many :museum_objects
has_many :termlists, through: :termlist_paths
end
class TermlistPath < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :path
belongs_to :termlist
end
class Termlist < ApplicationRecord
has_one :production_technique
has_one :preservation_material
has_many :termlist_paths
has_many :paths, through: :termlist_paths
end
```

The index

```
    <% @museum_objects.each do |museum_object| %>
       
      <tr>
        <td><%= museum_object.inv_number %></td>
        <td><%= museum_object.storage_location.storage.name_en%></td>
        <td><%= museum_object.storage_location.name_en%></td>         
        <td><%= museum_object.path.path.split("/").second.termlist_path.termlist %></td>
        <td><%= museum_object.path.path.split("/").third%></td>  
        <td><%= museum_object.path.path.split("/").fourth%></td>  
        <td><%= museum_object.path.path.split("/").fifth%></td>         
         <td><%= museum_object.production_technique.termlist.name_en%></td>  
         <td><%= museum_object.preservation_material.termlist.name_en%></td>           
        </tr>      
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Is Path supposed to be some kind of classification system like the dewey decimal system? Or is path.paths some kind of compound foreign key like used in the Ancestry gem? Anyhow you should not be letting this string splitting crazyness leak into your view. Rather your model should provide methods that encapsulate whatever it is you're doing so that you can actually cover it with tests without parsing HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, path.paths is a foreign key that refers to the id of termlist_path and termlist_path has a foreign key that refers to termlist.

Comment: Yeah the rest of this code makes no sense. When you call `split` you're implicitly calling to `to_s` on the relation and then you're trying to call a method that belongs to a model instance on and string. There is also the pluralization problem in `has_many :termlist`and the fact you're calling `term_list.termlist` . I'm really struggling to see what you're actually trying to do here.

Comment: Maybe start over and tell us what the real world problem is that the code is trying to solve and what the desired result is. You also most likely need to break the problem down into managable chunks instead of asking a very vague question that covers your entire domain and then just giving us an error in some code thats fundamentially broken without a description of what the code is even supposed to do. Sorry if this sounds like whining but I'm trying to help you ask a question that actually will get answered.

Comment: The code overall replaces some numbers in some tables like path.path with some words stored in termlist table but there is in between table called termlit_path. But my main problem is that path.path is like /750/760/775/783, so I have to split it first to 750, 760, 775, 783 so I can refer every number to a specific word in termlist.

Comment: Why do you think this is a good idea instead of using a join table? Multiple values in a single column violates first normal form and it is not how assocations work in Rails. Isn't that why you have a `termlist_paths` table?

Comment: Yes, termlist_path is a join table.